# With strapi, how to display the markdown in my gatsby frontendë

Tags: frontend, markdown, gatsby, strapi

I use strapi as a CMS, and I return "rich text markdown" fields,

I can't formatë the markdown in my frontend with gatsby.

Do you have any solutions ? THANKS !

I tried modules like "react markdown" but it doesn't work with my version of gatsby which is in 2..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First, installing the CKEditor 5 plugin in Strapi, followed by
  rebuilding and restarting the Strapi app.
- Once the app is running, navigate to the content builder in your
  Strapi and modify the default rich text box to CKEditor 5 rich text
  box (custom), adjusting the content according to your desired
  structure (utilizing features such as bullets, text color, and text
  indent).
- In your frontend use this tag
  `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html:content.Blog_content.data.Blog_content }}></div>`

you definetly get the format you want.this one is working for me.